# Using Mechanize to modify the form

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

I am using python 2.7 to modify the URL form but it does not let me do it. please help

This is what I tried so far.

```
#@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore
import re
import mechanize
import cookielib
## //*[@id="license"]
## //*[@id="state"] 

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open("http://www.autoreturn.com/app/search")

# Select the first (index zero) form
print [form for form in br.forms()][0]

plate = "GEL997" 
# User credentials
# br.select_form(id="searchParameters")

br.form['license'] = plate
br.form['licenseState'] = 'MD'


#response = br.response()
#a = response.read()
#print a
for f in br.forms():
    print f.name


response = br.submit() 
content = response.read() 
result = re.findall(r'[Ss]earch', content) 
print result[0]
```

Comment: You are using `browser.forms()`, I guess you meant to use `br.forms()` instead?

Comment: yes sorry, let me fix it. Again it still does not work :( please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing called `licence` or `liceneState`. The following code will submit the query successfully:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
res = br.open('http://www.autoreturn.com/app/search')

br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
br.form['l'] = 'GEL997'
br.form['region'] = ['BCO-MD']
br.form['s'] = ['MD']
r = br.submit()
print r.read()
```

Use the print out of the following code to get valid values for the dropdown menus:

```
for control in br.form.controls:
    print control
    print "type=%s, name=%s value=%s" % (control.type, control.name, br[control.name])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there's only one form and the form has no name, you can do this to get the form:

```
#Change this
print [form for form in br.forms()][0]
#to
br.form = [form for form in br.forms()][0]
```

And then a few more changes are:

```
#Change this
br.form['license'] = plate
br.form['licenseState'] = 'MD'
#To
br.form['l'] = plate
br.form['s'] = ['MD',]
```

EDIT: I think you're missing values for the first field dropdown 'region' too.
Looks like the license field has multiple name tag with 'license' and 'l', same as the 'licenseState'
Then try to submit again see what do you get.